# Is there a way to take an element from a list and use it in the name of a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list:

`questions = ['a','b','c','d','e']`

And I want to make a variable named after an element in this list:

`questions[2] = 'Hello world'`

This is the way I thought I could do it but when I try to print it:

`print(b)`

I get this error:

`NameError: name 'b' is not defined`

Obviously, python has made an entirely new variable called 'questions[2]'. How can I get python to recognize questions[2] as 'b' and not the 'questions[2]'?

Comment: > python has made an entirely new variable called 'questions[2]',

 will no, it will assign the cell at index `2` (previously holding value `'c'`) the new value `'Hello world'`. Note: list Indexing starts at 0 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the difference between b and 'b'? You are missing between variable's name and value.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to post a comment :) so the only way is to make an answer. Please make it a comment if possible!

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible, there really shouldn't be any reason to do this. But anyways you can use `exec()`.

```
questions = ['a','b','c','d','e']
exec(questions[1] + ' = "Hello world"')
print(b)
```

Note that using `exec()` is generally discouraged. Perhaps a dictionary would suit your needs instead.

Comment: I don't understand what the exec() is doing, could you elaborate on what is going on?

Comment: It executes the string as if it were a python statement, thus assigning `"Hello world"` to the variable `b` .